# Partial derivative of $F{\equiv}0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

If you have a function $F{\equiv}0$ then is the partial derivative of $F$ with respect to any of its variables $0$? Specifically, when we have Charpit's equations for a PDE $F(x,y,u,p,q) = 0$, where $u=u(x,y)$, $p= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $q= \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, and parameterising the initial data curve with $s$ and the characteristics with $t$, then in my lecture notes it says that if $F{\equiv}0$ in the domain of definition then this implies $\frac{\partial F}{\partial s}{\equiv}0$, however we can't claim that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial u}{\equiv}0.$ Why is this?

(If this is unclear please look at page 5 in these notes http://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/3078/40/B5b2.pdf)